"user?.user_metadata.display_name" comes out as undefined, next.js
I'm trying to make a chatroom using next.js, but for some reason, that specific string keeps resulting in undefined, even though (in my database), it is absolutely defined
const user = useUser((state) => state.user);

    const newMessage = {
      id,
      text,
      sent_by: user?.id,
      is_edited: false,
      created_at: new Date().toISOString(),
      users: {
        id: user?.id,
        avatar_url: user?.user_metadata.avatar_url,
        created_at: new Date().toISOString(),
        display_name: user?.user_metadata.display_name,
      },
    };

all of the other values load just fine, including avatar_url, but display_name just refuses to load, and yes, that's the correct name for discord OAuth
i then just render it with addMessage(newMessage as Imessage);
the "useUser" code comes from here:
import { User } from "@supabase/supabase-js";
import { create } from "zustand";

interface UserState {
  user: User | undefined;
}

export const useUser = create<UserState>()((set) => ({
  user: undefined,
}));

and Imessage file is:
import { User } from "@supabase/supabase-js";
import { create } from "zustand";

export type Imessage = {
  created_at: string;
  id: string;
  is_edited: boolean;
  sent_by: string;
  text: string;
  users: {
    avatar_url: string;
    created_at: string;
    display_name: string;
    id: string;
  } | null;
};

interface MessageState {
  messages: Imessage[];
  addMessage: (message: Imessage) => void;
}

export const useMessage = create<MessageState>()((set) => ({
  messages: [],
  addMessage: (message) =>
    set((state) => ({ messages: [...state.messages, message] })),
}));

it's weird because every single other string load just fine, just that one in specific doesn't.
tried setting it to user?.user_metadata?.display_name, changed interface around to match my database's column order.
what i expected was for the display_name show up correctly, but it's just an empty string.
full code is:
"use client";
import { Imessage, useMessage } from "@/lib/store/messages";
import { useUser } from "@/lib/store/user";
import { supabaseReceiver } from "@/lib/supabase/browser";
import React from "react";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

export default function ChatInput() {
  const user = useUser((state) => state.user);
  console.log(user);
  const addMessage = useMessage((state) => state.addMessage);
  const supabase = supabaseReceiver();
  const handleSendMessage = async (text: string) => {
    const id = uuidv4();
    const newMessage = {
      id,
      text,
      sent_by: user?.id,
      is_edited: false,
      created_at: new Date().toISOString(),
      users: {
        id: user?.id,
        avatar_url: user?.user_metadata.avatar_url,
        created_at: new Date().toISOString(),
        display_name: user?.user_metadata.display_name,
      },
    };
    addMessage(newMessage as Imessage);
    const { error } = await supabase.from("messages").insert({ text });
    if (error) {
      toast.error(error.message, {
        position: "top-center",
        autoClose: 5000,
        hideProgressBar: false,
        closeOnClick: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        draggable: true,
        progress: undefined,
        theme: "colored",
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="fixed bottom-0 left-0 w-full p-5 border-t border-green-500 bg-[#1b1b1b] z-10">
      <input
        className="w-full p-2 bg-black border border-green-500 text-green-300 placeholder-green-500"
        placeholder="Type a message..."
        onKeyDown={(e) => {
          if (e.key === "Enter") {
            handleSendMessage(e.currentTarget.value);
            e.currentTarget.value = "";
          }
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

the middleware code (for handling database):
import { createServerClient, type CookieOptions } from "@supabase/ssr";
import { NextResponse, type NextRequest } from "next/server";

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  let response = NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      headers: request.headers,
    },
  });

  const supabase = createServerClient(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL!,
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!,
    {
      cookies: {
        get(name: string) {
          return request.cookies.get(name)?.value;
        },
        set(name: string, value: string, options: CookieOptions) {
          request.cookies.set({
            name,
            value,
            ...options,
          });
          response = NextResponse.next({
            request: {
              headers: request.headers,
            },
          });
          response.cookies.set({
            name,
            value,
            ...options,
          });
        },
        remove(name: string, options: CookieOptions) {
          request.cookies.set({
            name,
            value: "",
            ...options,
          });
          response = NextResponse.next({
            request: {
              headers: request.headers,
            },
          });
          response.cookies.set({
            name,
            value: "",
            ...options,
          });
        },
      },
    }
  );

  await supabase.auth.getSession();

  return response;
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)"],
};

adding console.log(user) results in undefined, and no, it is not a cache issue.

Most likely it's issue with either your SQL query or the way you pass data to your state management library (zustand in this case). How do you pass data from database to client - with API or from server components?

i'm using supabase, so i just pass data using the official npm libraries

Can you provide code for the fragment responsible for this step? I believe the issue might be somewhere there

the code for passing the data should be in the "Imessage" code i shared earlier. just uses supabase-js and passes the user info

I see. What I'm asking for is the part, where you retrieve User object from database and pass it to zustand. Without it, unfortunately, I wouldn't be able to help. The code you provided covers the part, where you retrieve data from zustand and use it to create newMessage object

Might be helpful if you put the result of console.log(user) in the question. Would make troubleshooting much easier.

just says "undefined", tried printing it with "user.user_metadata", anyways, i've attached a middleware.ts to the post if that's what you meant to pass the user
